# Chose a person from a list of ~10000, with 1 optional filter by group (~1000 groups)

Tags: website-design, filter

I'm looking for a sane way to choose 1 person out of tens of thousands, optionally being able to filter the list by group - but there are almost as many groups.

The only option I've come up with is to use [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) twice - one for filter and one for person, but that seems rather ugly.

There's no need to filter by more than 1 group. Are there standard ways to do this?

Comment: Another alternative is chosen for the filter and a list box with search and [letter choosing](http://dribbble.com/shots/13715-Scroll-search-module) but that's almost as bad.

Comment: What is the criteria for choosing the person?

Comment: It really depends whether the user knows the name of the person to choose or not. If he does, there are many mechanisms available, with Outlook's being popular and useful.

Comment: We need a lot more detail. Why would someone do this? Do you know anything about the relation between asker and person? What other information is available?

Comment: OK, I should have mentioned the context, sorry. Yes, the person should probably know the name already, but obviously there might be more than one person with a given name.
It's for a horse race - the organizer needs to add the riders (and horses - I'm thinking of using the same thing for that) to the race.

Comment: When you have as many as 1000 items to filter through, it's better to include search functionality, especially when users know who they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I am imagining you have a form that has 2 select box/Chosen fields.

Does your user know who they want to choose, or are they randomly choosing someone?

If they know who they are going to choose, a simple list view that has a search and filter text field that filters items in the list view as the user types would be sufficient. The list view would be sorted A-Z by default. You can keep the Chosen for filtering by group. Chances are, if your users already know the name of the person they are after, they won't even bother with the group filter.

Comment: Thanks, that seems reasonable .. as for your questions, see also my comment in the question .. but yes, they know who they want to choose (but they may not know the person, just the name).